# Tableau - Line graph with timestamp and number data

Tags: graph, tableau-api

I have a CSV file that contains 150k+ records of wattage data that was collected over the course of 2 days. 
The CSV file is set up as shown below:

```
2016-04-07 19:20:52,44.679734706
2016-04-07 19:20:53,44.65862894
2016-04-07 19:20:54,44.668009281
2016-04-07 19:20:55,44.462228059
2016-04-07 19:20:57,45.116506814
2016-04-07 19:20:58,44.847994565
...
```

I would like to set up a line graph in Tableau, and I have created a parameter to represent the watts data:
[image]

However, the line graph only shows one values at a time:

[image]

How can I get Tableau to show all values over the given time period? I have attempted many different configurations and can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

So Parameter on tableau is a single select, (Allows one selection at a given time).

Why are you using Paramters ? 
Can't you directly use the wattage data column ?

Let's say data has 2 columns ,

```
Time, Wattage.
```

In the report you should use Time on column and on row use wattage and not parameter.

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Made an Edit -> 
I copied the data from the question and created a csv and you can see the image below and find out that the problem is solved by using wattage directly.
P.S. I had to use Seconds as I had limited data, You can change that to minutes and get the desired result.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.